# Are objects of parent classes implicitly created when instantiating an object of a child class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm confused by this code example:

I'm confused why the child method of draw is called first. I`m confused because when RoundGlyph is instantiated in main, dosen't the super constructor instantiate the parent object before the child?

```
class Glyph {
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("test"); // method will be called once you create a Glyph object, because when we create a round glyph before creating a glyph the super constructor will be called
    }

    void print2() {
        System.out.println("printed from print 2");
    }

    int y1;

    Glyph() {
        y1 = 5;
        System.out.println("y1 = " + y1);
        System.out.println("Glyph() before draw()");
        draw();
        System.out.println("Glyph() after draw()");
        print2();
    }
}

class RoundGlyph extends Glyph {
    int radius = 1;

    RoundGlyph(int r) {
        System.out.println("radius in RoundGlyph=" + radius);
        radius = r;
        System.out.println("RoundGlyph.RoundGlyph(), radius = "+ radius);
    }

    void draw() {
        System.out.println("RoundGlyph.draw(), radius = " + radius);
    }
}

public class PolyConstructors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RoundGlyph(5);
        //new Glyph();
    }
}
```

Comment: because it's called on an instance of RoundGlyph

Comment: Its true the constructor is implicitly called. draw() method is overriden in the child, so it will be invoked instead of parent one.

Comment: If you want to execute the parent's code, you can use super();

Comment: That why you should **never** call an overridable method from within the constructor.

Comment: See this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264611/method-called-by-parent-constructor-behaves-as-child-method

Comment: That's why you should only call `private` or `final` methods in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

> 1 - When ever you create a child class object, Child class constructor
>   is called. child class constructor call  parent class constructor.
>
> 2 - why parent class constructor called ?
>
> As you must know that child class have all the properties of parent
>   class. So when ever you create a child class object, all the property
>   of parent class is available in child class except private.
>
> 3 - what does constructor call do ?
>
> Constructor call assign default value to all its variable but do
>   not create an object of parent class.
>
> 4 - how can we prove that no object is created of parent class?
>
> as you know, We can inherit abstract class. and when ever child
>   class is object is created it also call abstract class constructor.
>
> and we know that we can not create an object of abstract class.

Answer (score -2):

In constructor `RoundGlyph(int r)` as a first row, before `System.out.println` java will implicitly call `supper()` constructor of the supper class `Glyph()`.
[see this post](https://dzone.com/articles/constructors-sub-and-super)

Answer (score -2):

The whole object is created (ie both child and parent structure), then the constructors are called in parent-to-child order.

If the constructor of the parent calls a method that is overridden in a child class, the child class' method is called (following the overriding semantics); there is nothing special about being in a constructor.

Note that it is a *very bad idea* to call a non-final method in a constructor (this is one of the items in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java") for exactly that reason: the child method overriding it may access child fields that have not been initialized yet.

eg

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        method();
    }
    void method() { System.out.println(); }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    String output = "hello";
    void method() { if (output.equals("hello")) System.out.println(output); }
}
```

The constructor of `Parent` will be called before `output` is initialized (due to superclass-first initialization), so the overriding `method` will run into a `NullPointerException`.